# Flutter Exception caught by widgets library (Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, widget, flutter-getx

I am new learner in flutter, I try to read the existing data from Firebase Firestore so that I can get back the data and perform update function in the page, but I encounter error when I click the button that redirect me to the update page is blank and given such Exception that I stated at below. Can anyone help me to identify which part is triggering this issues. Appreciate those help, thank you.

**Exception:**

```
═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while looking for parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The following ParentDataWidgets are providing parent data to the same RenderObject:
- Expanded(flex: 1) (typically placed directly inside a Flex widget)
- LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>](id: _ScaffoldSlot.body) (typically placed directly inside a CustomMultiChildLayout widget)
However, a RenderObject can only receive parent data from at most one ParentDataWidget.

Usually, this indicates that at least one of the offending ParentDataWidgets listed above is not placed directly inside a compatible ancestor widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the parent data was:
  RepaintBoundary ← NotificationListener<ScrollNotification> ← GlowingOverscrollIndicator ← Scrollable ← PrimaryScrollController ← ListView ← Expanded ← GetBuilder<TaskController> ← KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#0d8bd] ← _BodyBuilder ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      RenderObjectElement._findAncestorParentDataElement.<anonymous closure>
framework.dart:5792
#1      RenderObjectElement._findAncestorParentDataElement
framework.dart:5806
#2      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject
framework.dart:6157
#3      RenderObjectElement.mount
framework.dart:5828
#4      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
framework.dart:6376
...     Normal element mounting (73 frames)
#77     Element.inflateWidget
framework.dart:3953
#78     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
framework.dart:6512
#79     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
framework.dart:6524
...     Normal element mounting (318 frames)
#397    Element.inflateWidget
framework.dart:3953
#398    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
framework.dart:6512
#399    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
framework.dart:6524
...     Normal element mounting (682 frames)
#1081   Element.inflateWidget
framework.dart:3953
#1082   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
framework.dart:6512
#1083   Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3682
#1084   RenderObjectElement.updateChildren
framework.dart:6041
#1085   MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update
framework.dart:6537
#1086   Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3660
#1087   ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:4993
#1088   StatefulElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5133
#1089   Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4690
#1090   StatefulElement.update
framework.dart:5156
#1091   Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3660
#1092   ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:4993
#1093   Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4690
#1094   ProxyElement.update
framework.dart:5301
#1095   Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3660
#1096   ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:4993
#1097   Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4690
#1098   ProxyElement.update
framework.dart:5301
#1099   _InheritedNotifierElement.update
inherited_notifier.dart:107
#1100   Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3660
#1101   ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:4993
#1102   StatefulElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5133
#1103   Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4690
#1104   StatefulElement.update
framework.dart:5156
#1105   Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3660
#1106   ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:4993
#1107   Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4690
#1109   _InheritedNotifierElement.update
inherited_notifier.dart:107
#1110   Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3660
#1111   ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:4993
#1112   StatefulElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5133
#1113   Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4690
#1114   StatefulElement.update
framework.dart:5156
#1115   Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3660
#1116   ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:4993
#1117   Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4690
#1118   ProxyElement.update
framework.dart:5301
#1119   Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3660
#1120   ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:4993
#1121   StatefulElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5133
#1122   Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4690
#1123   StatefulElement.update
framework.dart:5156
#1124   Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3660
#1125   SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
framework.dart:6384
#1126   Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3660
#1127   SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
framework.dart:6384
#1128   Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3660
#1129   ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:4993
#1130   Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4690
#1131   ProxyElement.update
framework.dart:5301
#1132   Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3660
#1133   ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:4993
#1134   StatefulElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5133
#1135   Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4690
#1136   BuildOwner.buildScope
framework.dart:2743
#1137   WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
binding.dart:863
#1138   RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
binding.dart:381
#1139   SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
binding.dart:1289
#1140   SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
binding.dart:1218
#1141   SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
binding.dart:1076
#1142   _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:145:13)
#1143   PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:338:5)
#1144   _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

**Image:**
[image: Blank Page]

**Page that encounter this error:**

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_unnecessary_containers, avoid_print, unused_import, no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers, unused_label
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/controllers/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/controllers/firebase_controller.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/controllers/task_controller.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/light_dark_themes/theme.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/models/task.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/widgets/button.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/widgets/input_field.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class UpdatingTaskPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id, title, note, date, startTime, endTime, repeat;
  final int color, remind;
  final bool isCompleted;

  const UpdatingTaskPage(
      {super.key,
      required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.note,
      required this.date,
      required this.startTime,
      required this.endTime,
      required this.repeat,
      required this.color,
      required this.remind,
      required this.isCompleted});

  @override
  State<UpdatingTaskPage> createState() => _UpdatingTaskPageState();
}

class _UpdatingTaskPageState extends State<UpdatingTaskPage> {
  static TaskController controller = Get.put(TaskController());
  final task = controller.tasks.length;

  TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController noteController = TextEditingController();

  late DateTime _selecteDate = DateTime.now();
  late String _startTime =
      DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
  String _endTime = DateFormat('hh:mm a')
      .format(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(minutes: 60)))
      .toString();
  int _selectedRemind = 5;
  List<int> remindList = [5, 10, 15, 20];
  String _selectedRepeat = 'None';
  List<String> repeatList = ['None', 'Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly'];
  int _selectedColor = 0;
  List<Color> colorList = [
    bluishClr,
    yellowClr,
    redClr,
    greenClr,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    titleController.text = widget.title;
    noteController.text = widget.note;
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Update task!"),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // this icon button is for the user to signout
                  AuthController.instance.logout();
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.logout_rounded))
          ],
        ),
        body: GetBuilder<TaskController>(
            init: Get.put<TaskController>(TaskController()),
            builder: (controller) {
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: controller.tasks.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              //Title
                              InputField(
                                title: 'Title',
                                hint: 'Enter your title here...',
                                controller: titleController,
                              ),
                              //Note
                              InputField(
                                title: 'Note',
                                hint: 'Enter your note here...',
                                controller: noteController,
                              ),
                              //Date
                              InputField(
                                title: 'Date',
                                hint: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selecteDate),
                                child: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () => _getDateFromUser(),
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              //Date Range
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: InputField(
                                      title: 'Start Time',
                                      hint: _startTime,
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () =>
                                            _getTimeFromUser(isStartTime: true),
                                        icon: const Icon(
                                          Icons.access_time_rounded,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: InputField(
                                      title: 'End Time',
                                      hint: _endTime,
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () => _getTimeFromUser(
                                            isStartTime: false),
                                        icon: const Icon(
                                          Icons.access_time_rounded,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              //Remind
                              InputField(
                                title: 'Date',
                                hint: '$_selectedRemind minutes early',
                                child: DropdownButton(
                                  onChanged: (String? newVal) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _selectedRemind = int.parse(newVal!);
                                    });
                                  },
                                  items: remindList
                                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                        (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                          value: e.toString(),
                                          child: Text('$e minutes'),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                      .toList(),
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                                    size: 32,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  elevation: 3,
                                  underline: Container(height: 0),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                ),
                              ),
                              //Repeat
                              InputField(
                                title: 'Repeat',
                                hint: _selectedRepeat,
                                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                  onChanged: (String? value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _selectedRepeat = value!;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  value: widget.repeat,
                                  items: repeatList
                                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                        (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                          value: e,
                                          child: Text(e),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                      .toList(),
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                                    size: 32,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  elevation: 3,
                                  underline: Container(height: 0),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                ),
                              ),
                              //Color
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    const Text('Color'),
                                    Row(
                                      children: List.generate(
                                        colorList.length,
                                        (index) => Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              right: 5.0, top: 8),
                                          child: InkWell(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              setState(() {
                                                Value(widget.color);
                                                _selectedColor = index;
                                              });
                                            },
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                            child: CircleAvatar(
                                              backgroundColor: colorList[index],
                                              child: index == _selectedColor
                                                  ? const Icon(
                                                      Icons.check,
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                    )
                                                  : null,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ); // edited
                    } // edited
                    ),
              ); // edited
            } // edited
            ),
        floatingActionButton: MyButton(
            label: 'Save',
            onTap: () {
              // final title = titleController.text;
              // final note = noteController.text;
              _validateData();
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  _validateData() async {
    if (titleController.text.isNotEmpty && noteController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      print(1);
      _updateTaskToDb();
      Get.back();
    } else if (titleController.text.isEmpty || noteController.text.isEmpty) {
      print(2);

      Get.snackbar(
        'Required',
        'All fileds are required',
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        colorText: Colors.black,
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.warning_amber_rounded,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      print('######## Error Here ! ########');
    }
  }

  _updateTaskToDb() async {
    await FirestoreDB.updateTask(
      taskModel: Task(
        id: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
        title: titleController.text,
        note: noteController.text,
        isCompleted: false,
        date: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selecteDate),
        startTime: _startTime,
        endTime: _endTime,
        color: _selectedColor,
        remind: _selectedRemind,
        repeat: _selectedRepeat,
      ),
    );
  }

  _getDateFromUser() async {
    DateTime? _pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _selecteDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
    );
    if (_pickedDate != null) {
      setState(() {
        Value(widget.date);
        _selecteDate = _pickedDate;
      });
    } else {
      print('picked date empty !');
    }
  }

  _getTimeFromUser({required bool isStartTime}) async {
    TimeOfDay? _pickedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );
    if (_pickedTime != null) {
      setState(() {
        if (isStartTime) {
          _startTime = _pickedTime.format(context);
          print(_startTime);
        } else {
          _endTime = _pickedTime.format(context);
          print(_endTime);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the Expanded from the Listview builder

Answer (score 0):

`Expanded` can only be used as a direct child of a `Flex` widget like `Column` or `Row`. In this part of the code

```
        builder: (controller) {
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
```

it's not. So remove the `Expanded` there and directly return the `ListView`

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_unnecessary_containers, avoid_print, unused_import, no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers, unused_label
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/controllers/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/controllers/firebase_controller.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/controllers/task_controller.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/light_dark_themes/theme.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/models/task.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/widgets/button.dart';
import 'package:fyp_version1/widgets/input_field.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class UpdatingTaskPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id, title, note, date, startTime, endTime, repeat;
  final int color, remind;
  final bool isCompleted;

  const UpdatingTaskPage(
      {super.key,
      required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.note,
      required this.date,
      required this.startTime,
      required this.endTime,
      required this.repeat,
      required this.color,
      required this.remind,
      required this.isCompleted});

  @override
  State<UpdatingTaskPage> createState() => _UpdatingTaskPageState();
}

class _UpdatingTaskPageState extends State<UpdatingTaskPage> {
  static TaskController controller = Get.put(TaskController());
  final task = controller.tasks.length;

  TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController noteController = TextEditingController();

  late DateTime _selecteDate = DateTime.now();
  late String _startTime =
      DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
  String _endTime = DateFormat('hh:mm a')
      .format(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(minutes: 60)))
      .toString();
  int _selectedRemind = 5;
  List<int> remindList = [5, 10, 15, 20];
  String _selectedRepeat = 'None';
  List<String> repeatList = ['None', 'Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly'];
  int _selectedColor = 0;
  List<Color> colorList = [
    bluishClr,
    yellowClr,
    redClr,
    greenClr,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    titleController.text = widget.title;
    noteController.text = widget.note;
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Update task!"),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // this icon button is for the user to signout
                  AuthController.instance.logout();
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.logout_rounded))
          ],
        ),
        body: GetBuilder<TaskController>(
            init: Get.put<TaskController>(TaskController()),
            builder: (controller) {
              return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: controller.tasks.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              //Title
                              InputField(
                                title: 'Title',
                                hint: 'Enter your title here...',
                                controller: titleController,
                              ),
                              //Note
                              InputField(
                                title: 'Note',
                                hint: 'Enter your note here...',
                                controller: noteController,
                              ),
                              //Date
                              InputField(
                                title: 'Date',
                                hint: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selecteDate),
                                child: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () => _getDateFromUser(),
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              //Date Range
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: InputField(
                                      title: 'Start Time',
                                      hint: _startTime,
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () =>
                                            _getTimeFromUser(isStartTime: true),
                                        icon: const Icon(
                                          Icons.access_time_rounded,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: InputField(
                                      title: 'End Time',
                                      hint: _endTime,
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () => _getTimeFromUser(
                                            isStartTime: false),
                                        icon: const Icon(
                                          Icons.access_time_rounded,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              //Remind
                              InputField(
                                title: 'Date',
                                hint: '$_selectedRemind minutes early',
                                child: DropdownButton(
                                  onChanged: (String? newVal) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _selectedRemind = int.parse(newVal!);
                                    });
                                  },
                                  items: remindList
                                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                        (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                          value: e.toString(),
                                          child: Text('$e minutes'),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                      .toList(),
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                                    size: 32,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  elevation: 3,
                                  underline: Container(height: 0),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                ),
                              ),
                              //Repeat
                              InputField(
                                title: 'Repeat',
                                hint: _selectedRepeat,
                                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                  onChanged: (String? value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _selectedRepeat = value!;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  value: widget.repeat,
                                  items: repeatList
                                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                        (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                          value: e,
                                          child: Text(e),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                      .toList(),
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                                    size: 32,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  elevation: 3,
                                  underline: Container(height: 0),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                ),
                              ),
                              //Color
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    const Text('Color'),
                                    Row(
                                      children: List.generate(
                                        colorList.length,
                                        (index) => Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              right: 5.0, top: 8),
                                          child: InkWell(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              setState(() {
                                                Value(widget.color);
                                                _selectedColor = index;
                                              });
                                            },
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                            child: CircleAvatar(
                                              backgroundColor: colorList[index],
                                              child: index == _selectedColor
                                                  ? const Icon(
                                                      Icons.check,
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                    )
                                                  : null,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ); // edited
                    } // edited
              ); // edited
            } // edited
            ),
        floatingActionButton: MyButton(
            label: 'Save',
            onTap: () {
              // final title = titleController.text;
              // final note = noteController.text;
              _validateData();
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  _validateData() async {
    if (titleController.text.isNotEmpty && noteController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      print(1);
      _updateTaskToDb();
      Get.back();
    } else if (titleController.text.isEmpty || noteController.text.isEmpty) {
      print(2);

      Get.snackbar(
        'Required',
        'All fileds are required',
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        colorText: Colors.black,
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.warning_amber_rounded,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      print('######## Error Here ! ########');
    }
  }

  _updateTaskToDb() async {
    await FirestoreDB.updateTask(
      taskModel: Task(
        id: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
        title: titleController.text,
        note: noteController.text,
        isCompleted: false,
        date: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selecteDate),
        startTime: _startTime,
        endTime: _endTime,
        color: _selectedColor,
        remind: _selectedRemind,
        repeat: _selectedRepeat,
      ),
    );
  }

  _getDateFromUser() async {
    DateTime? _pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _selecteDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
    );
    if (_pickedDate != null) {
      setState(() {
        Value(widget.date);
        _selecteDate = _pickedDate;
      });
    } else {
      print('picked date empty !');
    }
  }

  _getTimeFromUser({required bool isStartTime}) async {
    TimeOfDay? _pickedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );
    if (_pickedTime != null) {
      setState(() {
        if (isStartTime) {
          _startTime = _pickedTime.format(context);
          print(_startTime);
        } else {
          _endTime = _pickedTime.format(context);
          print(_endTime);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```